# MySQL workbench not installing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MYSQL Workbench but shows the error that says

> Mysql workbench require the .net framework 4.5.2 to be installed.

But then when I download .net framework in my windows 8.1 it says

> Microsoft .net framework is already a part of your system. You don't need to install the .net framework 4.5 redistributable.

So now please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to fix the issue:

1) Go to: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=480542
and update the MySQL INTALLER 
to add Workbench 8.0

if that doesn't work

2) go to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-configuration-options.html
and look at possible resources to fix the issue,

3) Go to : Visual Studio and Modify by selecting 
Desktop development C++ 
this will allow you to update the required software.

if all of these methods fail completely uninstall Visual Studio and MySQL and continue to restart computer.
Reinstall: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=480542

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue MySQL workbench caused because of `.Net Framework  3.5` on Windows 8. Please install `.Net Framework 3.5` on Windows first and then try MySQL workbench or follow these references

Follow [Reference 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/error-microsoft-net-framework-4-is-already-a-part/6c8030a5-e829-4dd8-810b-df7ceca4a11c?msgId=e88346a4-bb20-4607-ad61-856e204313c9) or [Reference 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10)